# Let $a_n>0$ be bounded and: $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac 1 {a_n}=\frac 1 {\liminf_{n\to\infty}a_n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf, upper-lower-bounds

**Edit: there's something wrong with the question.**

I have got homework at Calculus and I can't prove this one:

> Let $a_n>0$ be a bounded sequence and so that:
>
> $\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac 1 {a_n}=\frac 1{\displaystyle\liminf_{n\to\infty}a_n}$
>
> **Prove that $a_n$ converges.**

Generally, if we'd show that:

$\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac 1 {a_n} = \frac 1 {\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n}$

We're done because from plugging it in the given we'll see that

${\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n} = {\displaystyle\liminf_{n\to\infty} a_n}$

And therefore $a_n$ converges.
So firstly, from the given equation we can induce that:

$\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac 1 {a_n}, \displaystyle\liminf_{n\to\infty}a_n \neq 0$

Then we can easily prove that $\frac 1 {a_n}$ is bounded as well.

So, by B.W we can say that there exists a converged subsequence so that:

${\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty}\ a_n}$ = ${\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}\ a_{n_k}}$

From here we can say that the given applies also for subsequences of $a_n$ :

$\displaystyle\limsup_{k\to\infty}\frac 1 {a_{n_k}}=\frac 1 {\displaystyle\liminf_{k\to\infty}a_{n_k}}$

I didn't get anything out of that but that's what I've tried.

Thanks ahead!

Comment: There must be something wrong. All positive sequences satisfy that condition.

Comment: $2,1/2,2,1/2,\ldots$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Yeap, I guess something's wrong with the question. I'll see what's wrong.